# Maven Tycho compilation failure

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I am using maven and tycho plug-in to build an eclipse RCP application. I use some java 8 features like lambda expression, but it could not build correctly because of compilation failure.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.0.0:compile (default-compile) on project ***.***: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:      
[ERROR]     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
[ERROR]             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Method references are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
[ERROR] 2 problems (2 errors)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

My questions are:

- Do you think the files **.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs** and **.classpath** (I guess not for this one) are necessary for the build of maven tycho? Do I have to explicitly define java 8 in those files?
- Do I have to specify something else in the **pom** files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in [the tycho-compiler-plugin documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#useProjectSettings), the information in file ***.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs*** will be passed to the compiler.

It is necessary then to update the file as follow:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
```

Comment: How about removing those lines from .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs and just use the maven.compiler-properties from the pom.xml? That way you avoid misleading double configuration.

Comment: As long as it works, it's good. It's just a question of choice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the source level in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<project>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
</project>
```

This has nothing to do with tycho, it is the compiler plugin.

You can alternatively configure the plugin itself.

Please refer to [this page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

Comment: Before using lambda expression of java 8, it compiled and built normally, even without specifying the option you mentioned. Do you think it is the original cause?

Comment: Adding method references is enough reason for maven to complain, if source level is put to a level less than Java 8. Method references and lambda are new features of Java 8.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to add these two properties in my root pom. However concerning the first question, do you think maven/tycho has anything to do with the file ***.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs***? I just changed the file to have 
`org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8`
`org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8`
`org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8`, and it seems compiled. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't thing that tycho looks inside your Eclipse project files. AFAIK, it can compile any OSGi bundle, not necessarily an Eclipse RCP. So ideally, it would perfectly compile without the .setting directory and .classpath file. These files are usually not tracked by your revision control system.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think too. It should not be dependent on a specify IDE.

Comment: You can try by renaming the `.settings` dir, and give it a compile (`mvn clean install` from the command line). You may want to close Eclipse in the meantime, not to recreate a `.settings` dir.

Comment: I just found out that the settings in file **.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs** are passed to tycho compiler. Check it out [here](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#useProjectSettings)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was to set JAVA_HOME to the right JDK.